# generating system of the kernel of a module-transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, modules, transformation

Let $G ≠ 1$ be a group and A a commutative ring. Now, the group ring $A[G]$ is naturally an A-module.

Next, let's consider the transformation:

$$\phi: A[G] \to A, \sum_{g \in G} a_gg \mapsto \sum_{g \in G} a_g$$

Now, show that the submodule $ker(\phi)$ is generated by elements of the form $1_A 1_G - 1_A g$ with $g \in G$, $g ≠ 1_g$. Is this a minimal generating system?

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm familiar with generating systems when it comes to vector spaces, but I don't really know what to do in this case, when it comes to modules.

Answer (score 1):

The first question depends directly on
$$
\sum_{g \in G} a_{g} g
=
\left(\sum_{g \in G} a_{g}\right) 1_{G}
+
\sum_{g \in G, g \ne 1_{G}} a_{g} (g - 1_{G}).
$$

As to the second one, if
$$
\sum_{g \in G, g \ne 1_{G}} a_{g} (g - 1_{G}) = 0,
$$
then
$$
\sum_{g \in G, g \ne 1_{G}} a_{g} g
=
\left(\sum_{g \in G} a_{g}\right) 1_{G},
$$
which means, comparing the two sides, that $a_{g} = 0$ for all $g$.